# Does a "Pyramid List" data-structure already exist?

Tags: data-structures, database-design, embedded

I am thinking about data structures which can be used in environments such as embedded/memory-constrained/filesystem and came upon an idea for a list-like data structure which has O(1) {access, insert, pop} while also *always* having O(1) push (non-amortized), even if it can only be grown by a *constant amount* (i.e. 4KiB). I cannot find an example of it anywhere and am wondering if it exists, and if so if anyone knows of a reference implementation.

The basic structure would look something like this:

PyramidList contains

- a `size_t numSlots`
- a `size_t sizeSlots`
- a `void** slots` pointer to an array of pointers of size `sizeSlots` with pointers to values in indexes up to `numSlots`

The `void **slots` array has the following structure for each index. These are structured in such a way that `2^i = maxValues` where `i` is the index and `maxValues` is the maximum number of values that can exist at that index or less (i.e. the sum of the count of all values up to that index)

- index 0: contains a pointer directly to a single value (`2^0 = 1`)
- index 1: contains a pointer directly to a single value (`2^1 = 2`)
- index 2: contains a pointer to an array of two values (`2^2 = 4`)
- index 3: contains a pointer to an array of four values (`2^3 = 8`)
- index 4: contains a pointer to an array of eight values (`2^4 = 16`)
- .. etc
- index M: contains a pointer to an array of MAX_NUM_VALUES (`2^M = MAX_NUM_VALUES*2`)
- index M+1: contains a pointer to an array of MAX_NUM_VALUES
- index M+2: contains a pointer to an array of MAX_NUM_VALUES
- etc

Now, suppose I want to access index `i`. I can use the [BSR](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_20.html) instruction to get the "power of 2" of the index. If it is less than the power of 2 of MAX_NUM_VALUES then I have my index. If it is larger than the power of 2 of MAX_NUM_VALUES I can act accordingly (subtract and divide). Therefore I can look up the array/single-value in O(1) time and then access the index I want in O(1) as well. Pushing to the PyramidList requires (at most):

- allocating a new MAX_NUM_VALUES and adding it's pointer to `slots`

  - In some cases `slots` might not be able to hold it and would have to be grown as well, so this is only *really* always O(1) up to some limit, but that limit is likely to be extreme for the use cases here.
- inserting the value into the proper index

### A few other benefits

- Works great for (embedded/file-system/kernel/etc) memory managers that have a maximum alloc size (i.e. can only allocate 4KiB chunks)
- Works great when you truly don't know how large your vector is likely to be. Starts out extremely small and grows by known amounts
- Always having (near) constant insertion may be useful for timing-critical interrupts/etc
- Does not leave fragmented space behind when growing. Might be great for appending records into a file.

### Disadvantages

Is likely less performant (amortized) than a contiguous vector in nearly every way (even insertion). Moving memory is typically less expensive than adding a dereference for every operation, so the amortized cost of a vector is still probably smaller.

Also, it is not truly always O(1) since the `slots` vector has to be grown when all the slots are full, but this only happens when `currentNumSlots*2*MAX_NUM_VALUES` have been added since the last growth.

Comment: What is the difference between this structure and an array ? From what I understand, an array would present the same features.

Comment: always O(1) growth even without efficient memory allocation (i.e. only able to grow 1 page at a time)

Answer (score 1):

When you exceed the capacity of an array of size X, and so allocate a new array of size 2X, you can then incrementally move the X items from the old array into the start of the new array over the next X append operations.  After that the old array can be discarded when the new array is full, just before you have to allocate a new array of size 4X.

Therefore, it is not necessary to maintain this list of increasing-size arrays in order to achieve O(1) appends (assuming that allocation is O(1)).  Incremental doubling is a well-known technique in the de-amortization business, so I think most people desiring this sort of behaviour would turn to that first.

Nothing like this is *commonly* used, because memory allocation can almost never be considered O(1).  Applications that can't afford to copy a block all at once generally can't afford to use any kind of dynamic memory allocation at all.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how array reallocation generally works. Note the point is not "increasing-size" arrays but rather that there is a cap on the array size.

The point about memory allocation being slow is a good one -- this would be useless without a fast source of memory blocks.